# Not getting top 1 element when caling API of SAP Successfactor using RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured, sap-successfactors

I'm trying to call SAP SF API calls using RestAssured in my application. The service is given parameter as top 1 .

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://sandbox.api.sap.com/successfactors/odata/v2/PerGlobalInfoCHN?%24top=1";
        RequestSpecification httpPost = RestAssured.given().headers("ApiKey","*key*");

        Response response= httpPost.request(Method.GET);

        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println("Response Body is :"+response.getBody().prettyPrint());
```

The output should be only one top element but I'm getting all the results.
When same URL is given in postman , it returns top 1 only.
What is the issue here? Do we have to provide top=1 as a parameter in header?

Comment: did you try $ instead of %24? maybe your encoding with this rest-whatever does not work, because the URL works, but the filter not ...